# Using height_field and width_field attribute in ImageField of Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model

```
class Anh_chi_tiet(models.Model):
    du_an       = models.ForeignKey(Du_an)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    url         = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', height_field='50', width_field='100')
    url_detail  = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', height_field='200', width_field='400')
```

I always receive this error:

```
'Anh_chi_tiet' object has no attribute '100'
```

It seems Django require both the fields in the same table Anh_chi_tiet to save height_field and width_field.

How can I directly set these values without append new fields in my table?

Comment: Here is one of the solution by @Nifled, hope that helps - [ImageField image_width and image_height auto fill for existing database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064339/imagefield-image-width-and-image-height-auto-fill-for-existing-database)

Answer (score 26):

`height_field` represents a property of your model which is used to store the height.

```
class Anh_chi_tiet(models.Model):

  url_height=models.PositiveIntegerField()
  url_width=models.PositiveIntegerField()
  url = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', height_field='url_height', width_field='url_width')
```

Notice `height_field='url_height'`

Comment: Are there any way to set height_field and width_field directly without create  url_height and url_width fields?

Answer (score 15):

I think you are misunderstanding what the height_field and width_field attributes are for.

The height_field isn't used to *change* the height. It's used to record what the height *already is*.

This way you can do something like

```
<img src="..." height={{my_instance.my_height_field}} />
```

without having to read the file.

If you are trying to resize all images uploaded via an ImageField, check here:
[Image resizing with django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164930/image-resizing-with-django/1164988#1164988)