# Using Pillow with Python 3

Tags: python-3.3, python-imaging-library

I'm not having much luck using Pillow with Python 3.3.2 and I'd be grateful for some help. My problem is that after installing Pillow, I can't import Image.

My setup:
I've got Linux Mint 16 installed (on an HP Pavilion dv7 laptop).
I've got Python 3.3.2+ installed, and it's working fine.
I've got Python 2.7.5+ installed, and it's working fine.

What I did:
I followed the instructions at http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html to install Pillow v2.4.0 (PIL fork):

I started with:

```
~$ pip install Pillow
```

I installed python-setuptools with:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
```

and also, for python 3:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools
```

I installed "prerequisites on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" thus:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
```

(*Mint 16 is based on Ubuntu 13.10, but I didn't find a list of prerequisites for any later version*)

What happened:
With python 2,
import image
worked and I could open a .png image and show it.
But with python 3,
'import image'
gave **'no module named Image'** and
'from PIL import Image'
gave **'no module named PIL'**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The source of the above: http://controlaltfire.com/blog/?cat=1

Answer (score 30):

After much digging, and since there's been no other answer forthcoming, I'll answer my own question. This works for the pillow installation for python3.4:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools

$ sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk

$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip

$ sudo pip3 install Pillow

$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick

$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/display /usr/bin/xv
```

Then in the python3.4 interactive shell enter:

```
>>> from PIL import Image

>>> im = Image.open("someimage.jpg")
>>> im.show()
```

And voilá, the image appears!

Most helpful sites:

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/427358/install-pillow-for-python-3

Python 3 is a beautiful language, and it's getting there, but installing and using its imaging library shouldn't be so hard to do!

Comment: For me it was pip3.2 install, just if anyone else has the same issue, as i had

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.04 doing `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools` then installing pillow in a virtualenv was all that was required.

Comment: Update: `sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev zlib1g-dev     libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev k8.5-dev`

Comment: @Tom Wouldn't hurt to go through all dependencies though. It will tell you when something is already installed and skip it.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you get this error is that you have not correctly installed python interpreter or your pip folder is misplaces. 
Simply download a [new interpreter] (https://www.python.org/downloads/)! and you are good to go.