# django ubuntu error pillow 3.0.0 install error

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I failed trying to install Pillow 3.0.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 and python 3.4.3 from virtualenv.  everytime I get error:

pip install pillow

```
  Building using 2 processes
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/decode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/encode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/map.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/display.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/outline.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/path.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/MspDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Incremental.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o -L/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/lib -L/usr/local/lib -ljpeg -lz -o build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/PIL/_imaging.cpython-34m.so
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/_imaging.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/decode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/encode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/map.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/display.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/outline.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/path.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BitDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Blend.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Chops.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Copy.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crc32.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Draw.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Effects.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/EpsEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/File.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Filter.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/FliDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GetBBox.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/HexDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Histo.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/LzwDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ModeFilter.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/MspDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Negative.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Pack.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PackDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Palette.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Paste.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantOctree.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHash.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHeap.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcdDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Point.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RankFilter.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Storage.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Incremental.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
  error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pillow
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow
    Complete output from command /home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-c_53bm8a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/site/python3.4/pillow:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running egg_info
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/_imaging.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Resample.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Crop.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Geometry.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Matrix.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Quant.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/RawDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/python3.4m -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -c libImaging/XbmEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    Building using 2 processes
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/decode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/encode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/map.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/display.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/outline.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/path.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/MspDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Incremental.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o -L/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/lib -L/usr/local/lib -ljpeg -lz -o build/lib.linux-i686-3.4/PIL/_imaging.cpython-34m.so
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/_imaging.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/decode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/encode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/map.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/display.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/outline.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/path.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Resample.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Bands.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BitDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Blend.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Chops.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Convert.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Copy.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crc32.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Crop.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Dib.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Draw.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Effects.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/EpsEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/File.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Fill.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Filter.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/FliDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Geometry.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GetBBox.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/GifEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/HexDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Histo.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/JpegEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/LzwDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Matrix.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ModeFilter.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/MspDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Negative.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Offset.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Pack.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PackDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Palette.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Paste.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Quant.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantOctree.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHash.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/QuantHeap.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcdDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/PcxEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Point.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RankFilter.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/RawEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Storage.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Unpack.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Incremental.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-i686-3.4/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-c_53bm8a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/include/site/python3.4/pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ah0pvkjy/pillow
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/507459/pil-install-in-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts

Comment: i have use ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype but not worked

Comment: What if you first install `libfreetype6-dev`? `(sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev)`

Comment: yes i have used this but given error  libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libfreetype6 (= 2.5.2-1ubuntu2) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpng-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install python3-pil` work?

Comment: thank you its work outside of virtualenv but not work in virtualenv how i will use from virtualenv

Comment: Is this link helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970006/using-pillow-with-python-3

Comment: same problem given error, but i can import PIL from python3 from outside of virtualenv but its not work in virtualenv

Comment: Please try to update your pip. maybe it's related to pip3

Comment: yes i have updated but not work (pip3 install pillow) i don’t know what happened i am totally fade up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060096/installing-pil-with-pip? please read all answers and comments

Comment: no nothing have change same problem

Comment: error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 error occur again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all at last solved my problem, I have install PIL in system

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pil
```

next I have copy this in my virtualenv

```
cp -R /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL /home/netai/lab/django/rangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```