# Python: How can I install a python module into a certain folder and import it

Tags: python

I want to import the Pillow module. But I have to install it just into the folder of the script which is using it. 
I tried to set a search path and import it:

```
sWorkDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print (sWorkDir)
sys.path.append(sWorkDir+"\\PIL_LOC")
sys.path.append(sWorkDir+"\\PIL_LOC\PIL")
import Image
```

Unfortunately, I get a

```
from . import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: why can't you let it install in the default directory(sites-packages) and use it from there ? am I missing something here?

Comment: Or even better, use a virtualenv.

Comment: No further module installation possible

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't make a comment under your original post, I'll make it like an answer.

I've found this, try to see if it works for you!

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-setuptools

$ sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk

$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip

$ sudo pip3 install Pillow

$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick

$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/display /usr/bin/xv
```

Then in the python3.4 interactive shell enter:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("someimage.jpg")
im.show()
```

Credits goes to: [Using Pillow with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970006/using-pillow-with-python-3)

Comment: I was more hoping to copy and paste the module somehow into the directory