# In which file should I write codes to resize Image file on Django?

Tags: python, django, resize, python-imaging-library

I'd like to resize image and save it to Database on `Django`. I found several web sites mentioned about resize of `Django`, some write in `models.py`, but the others write in `views.py`. In which file should I write codes, `views.py` or `models.py`?

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('original.jpg', 'r')
img.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('thumbnail.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=75, optimize=True)
```

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="...")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_somehting()
        super(Photo, self).save()
```

Comment: There is no definitive answer to that. When will image resize occur? On page load? On item save? You can always put this code in a separate py file anyway. It's all up to how you want to have your code organized.

Comment: @Wtower Thank you for your reply. Sorry, my question was obscure. For Instance, it occurs when a user upload his/her photo.

Comment: Take a look at this one, covers also your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164930/image-resizing-with-django

Comment: @Wtower Sorry for late reply. The link is very nice. One of answers only use PIL and doesn't use libraries. I learned a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use imagekit for that, eg:

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import Resize

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    photo = models.ProcessedImageField(upload_to="...", processors=[Resize(650, 402))
```

In your models seems better, since the picture will always be resized (in your website's actions and in the admin panel).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know Imagekit. I am outside now, so I will try later. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best practice is when you use background jobs such as `celery` or something else, and call it in model saving mode.

It's better to use `Pillow` package and `sorl` and its `thumbnail` to make any size thumbnail and index it automatically via `redis`

Consider this gist:

```
import picke
create_thumbnail_images.apply_async([pickle.dumps(self.image_path), USER_IMAGE_THUMB_SIZES], countdown=5)
```

You can can above sample code in `save` action of your model to create thumbnails in background, so you never become blocked for creating these thumbnails.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I use Redis, so Sorl is nice. Thank you so much.

Comment: @yamachan if it helped, i appreciate to make it answer